# I am currently serving my static files in Django. How do I use Apache2 to do this?

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, unix

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

As you can see, I have a directory called "media" under my Django project.

I would like to delete this line in my `urls.py` and instead us Apache to serve my static files. What do I do to my Apache configs (which files do I change) in order to do this?

By the way, I installed Apache2 like normal:

```
sudo aptitude install apache2
```

Comment: After you read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/static-files/#howto-static-files what SPECIFIC questions do you have?  Please read this and update your question with any specific things that you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would read Django's [official static files docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and [apache mod_python documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#serving-media-files).

> This example sets up Django at the
>   site root but explicitly disables
>   Django for the **media** subdirectory and
>   any URL that ends with .jpg, .gif or
>   .png:

```
<Location "/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
</Location>

<Location "/media">
    SetHandler None
</Location>

<LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">
    SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>
```